# The limit of $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^3+k}$

Tags: analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

How can I find the limit of $(a_n)_{n \in\mathbb{N}}$?
$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^3+k}$$

My Attempts
$$\frac{k^2}{n^3+n} \leq \frac{k^2}{n^3+k} \leq \frac{k^2}{n^3}$$

$$a_n = \frac{1}{{n^3}}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{1}{{n^3}}\cdot \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=$$
$$a_n = \frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{n^26}$$

I know that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{a_n} =\frac{1}{3}$, but it is not clear to me how $ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{n^26} = \frac{1}{3}$?

How can I continue to work this equation?
 It would be correct to use L´Hospital?

Comment: Note, it is not true that $a_n=\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2$. It should be $a_m\leq \dots$. So even if you know the limit of $\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^2}$, you don't know the limit of $a_n$.

Comment: Can I know the limit of $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^3+k}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to compute:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \dfrac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^2}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \dfrac{2n^2+3n+1}{6n^2}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \dfrac{2+\dfrac{3}{n}+\dfrac{2}{n^2}}{6}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \dfrac{2+0+0}{6}=\dfrac 13$$

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a theorem from high school that

> The limit of a rational function at infinity is the limit of the ratio of the highest degree terms of its numerator and denominator.

Applying this, you get at once, since the highest degree term of a product is the product of the highest degree terms of each factor:
$$\lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^2} = \lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{n\cdot 2n}{6n^2} =\frac{2n^2}{6n^2}=\frac13.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{n^26}=\frac{\frac{(n+1)}{n}\frac{(2n+1)}{n}}{6}=\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})(2+\frac{1}{n})}{6} $$